# Retrieving SMS messages from Inbox

Tags: android, sms

I am working on android application and I am trying to get a list of messages from the devices SMS inbox. In the inbox I have 2 messages received from one contact number and 1 message from another contact number. However, I only seem to be getting out of message from each contact not all of them.

Below is the code I am using

```
public void retrieveSMSMessages()
    {
        String address = "";
        String body = "";
        Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String[] reqCols = new String[] {"_id", "address", "body"};
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(inboxUri, reqCols, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the call cursor.moveToFirst(); .
You move the cursor to the first position, then you call moveToNext(). You're skipping the first position.